# How to count unique text in multiple column with mixture of number and text?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

If:

```
column A 
a123 
b345 
c567 
1234 
1245

column D 
a123 
b234 
c223 
4567 
7689
```

How to put the formula to count the number of unique text in both column A and D? So that there is 5 count of unique text in both column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to count unique in A column:

  ```
  =COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A)
  ```
- to count unique in A and D column via 1 formula:

  ```
  =COUNTUNIQUE({A1:A; D1:D})
  ```




  ```
  =COUNTUNIQUE({A1:A\ D1:D})
  ```

  [image: 0]
- to count unique in A and D per column:

  ```
  ={COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A), "", "", COUNTUNIQUE(D1:D)}
  ```




  ```
  ={COUNTUNIQUE(A1:A); ""; ""; COUNTUNIQUE(D1:D)}
  ```

  [image: 0]
- to count unique text in A and D:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IF(ISTEXT(UNIQUE({A1:A;D1:D})), 1, )))
  ```

Comment: Please note that both columns are mixture of texts and numbers. I just want to count the text, unique text, not including the plain numbers. 

=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IF(ISTEXT(UNIQUE(A1:A)), 1, )))

This formula is for column A only.. is there a formula for column A and D together?

Comment: in that case try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IF(ISTEXT(UNIQUE({A1:A;D1:D})), 1, )))`